# Autopopulate a field from a Detail Button URL

Tags: button, url, custom, action

I have a Detail Page Button with a URL.

It resides on the Case object and creates a custom object record.
On the custom object, there is a lookup to the case object. I would like
the CaseNumber to populate on the new record upon save.

Here is the URL:

```
https://naXX.salesforce.com/a0U/e?retURL=%2Fa0U%2Fo&RecordType=0121H00000XXXXX&ent=01IA000000XXXXX
```

How do I amend the URL so the CaseNumber populates the field on the new record?

Thank you.

Comment: so you are basically looking prepopulating the value of `Case__c` (the lookup field) on the custom object? Is this Classic?

Comment: Yes. I need to populate the Request__c (a lookup to the case object) with the CaseNumber value. And, yes, for now, they are still refusing to move from classic.  They despise Lightning.

Comment: this covers how to do Classic URL hacking: https://focusonforce.com/configuration/salesforce-url-hacking/